# In which context is the MidiInProc callback executed?

Tags: windows, concurrency, callback, midi

Help! Need peace of mind.
I'm finishing off writing a lighting control console application that uses the windows MidiInProc as a callback and a virtual MIDI port.

'Open the midi device and setup the call back
  ret=midiInOpen(@hDevice,devNo,cast(uinteger,@MidiInProc),0,CALLBACK_FUNCTION)

When a midi message is received, the midiInProc accesses a circular queue to store the midi messages so no messages are dropped (very important for theatre Lighting) and the main program dequeues them for subsequent processing.

How does the callback work. Does it interrupt the main program or run in its own thread or what?

Is there a possibility that the callback conflicts with the main program in trying to access the queue at the same time. If so how do I prevent this from happening?

Have used the program for 3 years and no problems have arisen so far but one never knows.

Comment: Removed the tag <[processing](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/processing/info)>. [Processing](https://processing.org/) is a flexible software sketchbook and a language for learning how to code within the context of the visual arts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The callback is invoked from another thread, most of the time. To prove it, consider this sample program adapted from a [midi sample program gist](https://gist.github.com/yoggy/1485181):

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <mmsystem.h>
#pragma comment(lib, "winmm.lib")

void CALLBACK MidiInProc(HMIDIIN hMidiIn, UINT wMsg, DWORD_PTR dwInstance, DWORD_PTR dwParam1, DWORD_PTR dwParam2)
{
    printf("Callback thread id=%ld\n", GetCurrentThreadId());
    switch (wMsg) {
    case MIM_OPEN:
        printf("wMsg=MIM_OPEN\n");
        break;
    case MIM_CLOSE:
        printf("wMsg=MIM_CLOSE\n");
        break;
    case MIM_DATA:
        printf("wMsg=MIM_DATA, dwInstance=%Ix, dwParam1=%Ix, dwParam2=%Ix\n", dwInstance, dwParam1, dwParam2);
        break;
    case MIM_LONGDATA:
        printf("wMsg=MIM_LONGDATA\n");
        break;
    case MIM_ERROR:
        printf("wMsg=MIM_ERROR\n");
        break;
    case MIM_LONGERROR:
        printf("wMsg=MIM_LONGERROR\n");
        break;
    case MIM_MOREDATA:
        printf("wMsg=MIM_MOREDATA\n");
        break;
    default:
        printf("wMsg = unknown\n");
        break;
    }
    return;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    HMIDIIN hMidiDevice = nullptr;;
    DWORD nMidiPort = 2;
    UINT nMidiDeviceNum;
    MMRESULT rv;

    printf("Main thread id=%ld\n", GetCurrentThreadId());

    nMidiDeviceNum = midiInGetNumDevs();
    if (nMidiDeviceNum == 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "midiInGetNumDevs() return 0...");
        return -1;
    }

    rv = midiInOpen(&hMidiDevice, nMidiPort, (DWORD_PTR)(void*)MidiInProc, 0, CALLBACK_FUNCTION);
    if (rv != MMSYSERR_NOERROR) {
        fprintf(stderr, "midiInOpen() failed...rv=%d", rv);
        return -1;
    }
    midiInStart(hMidiDevice);
    while (true) {
        if (!_kbhit()) {
            Sleep(100);
            continue;
        }
        int c = _getch();
        if (c == VK_ESCAPE) break;
        if (c == 'q') break;
    }
    midiInStop(hMidiDevice);
    midiInClose(hMidiDevice);
    return 0;
}
```

Executing it in my system, with 3 MIDI devices attached (#2 is a controller), I get this output after pressing and releasing one key:

```
Main thread id=9656 
Callback thread id=9656 
wMsg=MIM_OPEN 
Callback thread id=5684 
wMsg=MIM_DATA, dwInstance=0, dwParam1=513190, dwParam2=cfb 
Callback thread id=5684
wMsg=MIM_DATA, dwInstance=0, dwParam1=403180, dwParam2=eaa
```

You can inspect in [ProcessHacker2](https://processhacker.sourceforge.io/) or in SysInternals' [ProcessExplorer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer) your program threads while it is running:

[image: Process threads]

You may observe that there are at least 2 thread ids in your process: 9656 and 5684. Your `main()` function thread-id is 9656, and the callbacks for the `midiInOpen()` and `midiInClose()` function calls print the same id. But for the note events, the thread id is 5684. And this thread's start address corresponds to the `wdmaud.drv` module, which is a Windows driver.

This is a typical scenario for any process handling MIDI input: a [producer and consumer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Producer%E2%80%93consumer_problem) problem. Your approach is sound: you enqueue the received MIDI events in the callback function (the producer), and then another thread consumes the queued events. You will find many [lock free ring buffer](https://www.google.com/search?q=lock+free+ring+buffer) implementations that are suitable for the task.

There is another variant of the `midiInOpen()` function that uses the last argument flags CALLBACK_WINDOW or CALLBACK_THREAD. In that case, instead of a callback function, you provide a window handle or thread id to Windows, and your window or thread procedure will receive the MIDI messages enqueued and interleaved with other unrelated windows events. My preference is to use CALLBACK_FUNCTION.